# Wordpress Blog has an infinite redirect loop

Tags: loop, headers

i added the following code in the Header.php

```
<?php     
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ){    
?>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=<?php wp_login_url(); ?>">
<?php exit;    
   }    
else {
}
```

to redirect a user who is not logged in to wp-login.php
i didn't use wp_redirect as it was not working properly.
code was working fine but some how today it is causing infinity loop.
i have placed the code in header.php and i don't think wp-login.php calls header.php
can some one tell me what's the problem here
or any other suggestion
**thanks**

Answer (score 3):

Try using this in your header:

```
<?php 

if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) 
{
    wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
    exit();
}
```

Comment: +1 (not sure if for the right advice or for having a leica-style logo ;)

Comment: ha! Blame my designer! It is similar lol.